# For loop for running multiple regressions

Tags: stata, logistic-regression

I am new to Stata.

I know how to run logistic regressions individually and to predict values and residuals. I want to know how I can do this in a for loop.

If I have a y-variable and multiple x-variables, how can I run multiple Logistic regressions and predict the values and residuals? Specifically, how can I do the following in a loop:

```
logit y-variable x-variable1
predict values1
predict residuals1, res

logit y-variable x-variable1 x-variable2
predict values2
predict residuals2, res

logit y-variable x-variable1 x-variable2 x-variable3
predict values3
predict residuals3, res

logit y-variable x-variable1 x-variable2 x-variable3 x-variable4
predict values4
predict residuals4, res
```

Comment: This isn't legal code, as `-` characters are not allowed in variable names.

Answer (score 0):

```
forval j = 1/4 {
    local xvars `xvars' xvariable`j'
    logit yvariable `xvars'
    predict values`j'
    predict residuals`j', re
}
```

See also the results of typing

`help nestreg`

`search for loop`